# onAttach()-method is not being called, although there is a commit() of the fragment transaction

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am wondering, how I can figure out, why my onAttach-method is not getting called. There is a commit of the fragment transaction and a corresponding replace. My log-Messages and my debug steps are telling me, that the `onAttach()` method of my `QuotesFragment` class never got triggered.

Here is my forward procedure in my MainActivity-class:

```
private void forwardToQuotesFragment(){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, quotesFragment, QuotesFragment.QUOTES_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    ft.commit();
    // onAttach()-method of QuotesFragment is not getting called - why?
}
```

Comment: There might be some error/warning in log. Check the log

Comment: Thanks for this hint Akshay, here is the output of my console. As you can see, there is only one error mentioned which is printed below the other info-messages (onCreate) - so for me it looks like, all should be running fine. 

D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

I/QuotesFragment: onCreate()

I/QuotesFragment: onCreateView()

E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

V/RenderScript: Application requested CPU execution

V/RenderScript: 0x93522400 Launching thread(s), CPUs 8

Comment: method deprecated, look for updated usage.

Comment: Hi Karan, do you mean the change from onAttach(Activity activity) to onAttach(Context context)? If so, in my app I am using the current recommended version!

Comment: I maybe found the origin of the problem: my device runs on Android Lollipop (5.0.2). My app project is focused on Android 6+. The onAttach()-params changed from Android 5 to 6. This change could result in the missing call of onAttach - What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. As I mentioned in my prior comment, the reason for my issue was that on my cell phone Android 5.0.2 was installed and my app was created for Android 6.0 upwards.

Furthermore I used the android.app.*-classes. Now I changed those classes to the corresponding android-support-library-classes. That means my MainActivity extends from AppCompatActivity and my fragments from android.support.v4.app.Fragment. There is a need to update the fragment transaction procedure a little bit, as you can see below:

```
private void forwardToQuotesFragment(){
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, quotesFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```